# R: Merge rows without losing information

Tags: r

I periodically receive data from different sources regarding the sales of alcoholic beverages. 
In order to make the analysis easier, I created a master data with columns indicating the product ID for each data source, therefore it's easier to just make a join afterwards.

The ideal scenario is to have one row per product, however, I end up having multiple rows for the same product.

I have thousands of products, so it's hard to fix this manually. 
Is there an easy way to make this cleaning?

How it is:
[how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xygG.png)

How I would like to be:
[how I would like to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Oh3D.png)

Code for the data:

```
data_products <- tibble::tribble(
                           ~product_name, ~product_type, ~product_volume, ~product_alcohol, ~country,    ~region, ~brand_manager, ~product_id_vinmonopolet, ~product_id_vinhuset, ~product_id_cuveco, ~product_id_asko, ~product_id_SG, ~product_id_NAV,
               "Myken Arktisk Sommergin",         "Gin",             0.5,              47L, "Norway", "Nordland",       "Thomas",                10289002L,                   NA,          10289002L,               NA,             NA,              NA,
          "Myken Arktisk Sommergin 50cl",            NA,             0.5,               NA,       NA,         NA,       "Thomas",                       NA,            10289002L,                 NA,               NA,             NA,              NA,
          "Myken Arktisk Sommergin 50cl",            NA,             0.5,               NA,       NA,         NA,       "Thomas",                       NA,                   NA,                 NA,         5406301L,             NA,              NA,
  "Myken Arktisk Sommergin   47%   50cl",            NA,             0.5,               NA,       NA,         NA,       "Thomas",                       NA,                   NA,                 NA,               NA,       5406301L,              NA,
      "Myken Arktisk SommerGin 47% 50Cl",            NA,             0.5,               NA,       NA,         NA,       "Thomas",                       NA,                   NA,                 NA,               NA,             NA,       10289002L)
```

Comment: Hi José, I think this will require a bit of optimization of string comparisons (for example with `stringdist`). It will work a lot better if you can provide a larger set of your data with multiple products.

Comment: You say "I end up having multiple rows for the same product". Is this how the data comes or is it after some manipulation?

Comment: You could `grepl` "product_id" in `names(data_products)` to select all the columns with an ID and merge them in one column.